# MeteorJS wont stop creating starter files

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, meteor

I'm trying to get set up with a very basic MeteorJS application to play around with.  I created a client directory in which to house my client side code.  I moved my main html, js, and css file into that directory.

However, whenever I run the command to launch my application Meteor creates a new set of starter files in my root directory, causing me errors.  I know for the most part I don't have to keep starting and stopping the application as it refreshes on change.  But I feel like this isn't the expected behavior and it's starting to get annoying.  I've tried to research this, but it's been a bit difficult to write a search query for something like this.

I am running Meteor 1.1.0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Any ideas?

Comment: What command are you running exactly?

Comment: I was running `meteor` per a tutorial I was reading.  I just read through some help docs and tried `meteor start` instead and it appears to be working correctly.  Is that the command I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, so I've got to answer.

I believe I came across this problem once, and the solution is rather amusing :)

Try to create a new project (`$ meteor create thenameofyourproject`) -- that should do the thing! And if that doesn't work, reinstall Meteor.
It's definitely not a normal behaviour of the platform.

I've recreated what you've done on Trisquel 7 (Ubuntu fork) and Meteor 1.1.0.2, and everything works fine.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I was creating the project.  Just whenever I wanted to start the application, it seemed to basically re-create the project every time.  I deleted that project and created a new one.  I'm running updates at the moment and going to try again to see if I can replicate it

Answer (score 0):

After deleting my project and creating a new one, I am unable to replicate the issue.  Thanks to everyone for their comments.